# How to identify data gaps based on filenames on Python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, path, timestamp, filenames

It happens that I have a folder located at

`C:\Users\StoreX\Downloads\Binance futures data\AliceUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe`

which only contains 253 csv files with the following filenames:

```
1. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-01.csv
2. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-02.csv
3. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-03.csv
4. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-06.csv
5. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-09.csv
6. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-11.csv
7. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-12.csv
.
.
.
253. ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-13.csv
```

Each of those files contains the hourly price action of a particular asset, having in total 24 rows (no column names), and therefore, it can be assumed that **each filename corresponds to the price action data taken for a particular asset in a particular date**.

However, if you look closely at the example above, there are some files missing at the very beginning, which are:

```
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-04.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-05.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-07.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-08.csv
ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-10.csv
```

This obviously means I could not take into account those files that are previous to the missing files for developing a trading strategy.

So, I would first have to detect which files are missing based on its name, for then defining where to start plotting the price action to avoiding all of the of the possible gaps.

**Update: Here's what I have done so far:**

```
import os
import datetime

def check_path(infile):
    return os.path.exists(infile)   

first_entry = input('Tell me the path where your csv files are located at:')

while True:
    
    if check_path(first_entry) == False:
        print('\n')
        print('This PATH is invalid!')
        first_entry = input('Tell me the RIGHT PATH in which your csv files are located: ')
        
    elif check_path(first_entry) == True:
        print('\n')
        final_output = first_entry
        break

for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    if name.endswith(".csv"):
        print((name.partition('-')[-1]).partition('-')[-1].removesuffix(".csv"))
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-01
2021-06-02
2021-06-03
2021-06-06
2021-06-09
.
.
.
2022-02-13
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you have outlined a possible approach. What are you asking for? That someone writes the code for you?

Comment: I don't know how to get specifically the dates from the filenames for then comparing them with the real dates that have passed. @JanWilamowski

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: please show us your code along with expected and actual output and/or errors. The filenames are strictly formatted strings that make it easy to extract the date information. You can step through the list of files, analyze their names and use the data if appropriate.

Comment: Oh, wait a second, I have managed to deal with 50% of the task, here's that I did.
`import os`
`for name in os.listdir(path):`
    `if name.endswith(".csv"):`
        `print((name.partition('-')[-1]).partition('-')[-1].removesuffix(".csv"))`

Comment: Output: 

`2021-06-01`
`2021-06-02`
`2021-06-03`
`2021-06-06`
`2021-06-09`
etc...

Comment: Code updated in the original post btw

Comment: You'll want to keep the file names in a sorted list so you can access the next or previous entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you have a list of dates and try to find out what dates are missing if you compare the list against a date range based on min and max date in the list. [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) can help, ex:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

l = ["ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-01.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-02.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-03.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-06.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-09.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-11.csv",
     "ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-12.csv"]

# extract the dates, you don't have to use a regex here, it's more for convenience
d = [re.search(r"[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}", s).group() for s in l]

# to datetime
d = [datetime.fromisoformat(s) for s in d]

# now make a date range based on min and max dates in d
r = [min(d)+timedelta(n) for n in range((max(d)-min(d)).days+1)]

# ...so we can do a membership test with sets to find out what is missing...
missing = set(r) - set(d)

sorted(missing)
[datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 4, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 8, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Wow, that was cool. Thanks sir. I appreciate it. 